# Trouble using a custom tag correctly with Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-custom-tags

**Summary**

I've been trying to get a custom tag working in Django, but seemingly it wont register correctly.

The index file looks to load correctly, it just complains about the tag not being registered correctly.

What I've done right now is just to put the .py file where I register the tag inside an app that is in the django installed apps part.

Should I be doing something else to ensure the tag registers properly?

---

**Further info**

The error I get:

> Invalid block tag on line 1: 'show_loans'. Did you forget to register
>   or load this tag?

**The view where I call the tag**

index.html

```
{% show_loans %}
```

**The python file where i try to register the tag**

loansTable.py

```
from .models import Loan
from datetime import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag('loansTable.html')
def show_loans():
    l1 = Loan()
    l2 = Loan()
    l1.loanedDate_date = datetime.now
    l2.handinDate_date = datetime.now
    l2.loanedDate_date = datetime.now
    l2.handinDate_date = datetime.now
    loans2 =    { l1, l2 }
    return {'loans': loans2}
```

loansTable.html

```
<ul>
    {% for loan in loans %}
        <li> {{ loan }} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Folder structure:

```
-app
--templates
---customTemplates
----index.html
----loansTable.html
--loansTable.py
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to register your tag to a template. You just need to load it from there. Which you are already doing.

Therefore just replace:

```
@register.simple_tag('loansTable.html')
```

With this:

```
@register.simple_tag
```

You also need to put your custom tags in a `templatetags` directory. From the docs:

In your **index.html** you must load template tags by file name where you have registered your template tags.
*i.e. if you registered tag inside `custom_tags.py` file*

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it - don’t forget the **init**.py file to ensure the directory is treated as a Python package.

Comment: I tested that just now. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Doh09 Updated my answer

Comment: You need to register your tag inside `your_app/templatetags/custom_tags.py` and than load into your html file

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you exactly what is wrong: you did not load the tag in the template where you are using it, ie index.html.

```
{% load loansTable %}
{% show_loans %}
```

Also, you are confusing your tag types. The tag that renders another template is called an inclusion tag, so you should use that when you register it:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('loansTable.html')
def show_loans():
    ...
```

Comment: I think he thought he needed to specify which template to register it. Hence the name `loansTable.html`

Comment: Why would he be calling it in index.html then, rather than loansTable.html? The structure exactly matches an inclusion tag.

Comment: It's my first time using Django. Ended up going with the registering: @register.inclusion_tag('loansTable.html')
as well as putting the loansTable.py in templatetags and loansTable.html in templates. I then also used the load keyword in the index file and was afterwards able to use the tag as intended. I was aware that I wasn't doing things right but I was confused by the documentation. Thanks for the pointers to what I did wrong.